# I want to check the processing for the 'success_url' parameter of the 'Checkout \ Session :: create () method' in the Git-Hub code

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**The following PHP code works fine.**

```
   $checkoutSession = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'customer_email' => 'customer@example.com',
    'success_url' => 'https://xxxx/thanks.php',
```

---

[The description is also described in the document.](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-success_url)

> The URL the customer will be directed to after the payment or
>   subscription creation is successful.

---

**But I want to see in PHP code how the process to be redirected to 'success_url' is implemented.**

[stripe-php/lib/Checkout/Session.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Checkout/Session.php#L19)

```
<?php
namespace Stripe\Checkout;
/**
 * Class Session
 *
 * Omission
 *
 * @property string $success_url
 *
 * @package Stripe
 */
class Session extends \Stripe\ApiResource
{
    const OBJECT_NAME = "checkout.session";
    use \Stripe\ApiOperations\Create;
    use \Stripe\ApiOperations\Retrieve;
}
```

[stripe-php/lib/ApiOperations/Create.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/ApiOperations/Create.php)

```
trait Create
{
    /**
     * @param array|null $params
     * @param array|string|null $options
     *
     * @return \Stripe\ApiResource The created resource.
     */
    public static function create($params = null, $options = null)
    {
        self::_validateParams($params);
        $url = static::classUrl();
        list($response, $opts) = static::_staticRequest('post', $url, $params, $options);
        $obj = \Stripe\Util\Util::convertToStripeObject($response->json, $opts);
        $obj->setLastResponse($response);
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

Where is the process for 'success_url' implemented?

Comment: This is something you code yourself. Usually it's just where you say "thanks for your purchase, we'll send you an email when the product ships" or similar. This is all covered in https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment

Comment: Are you using the hosted UI? What the you mean how the "process" is implemented? Do you mean as in where the redirect is being done?